# How to get value of a field?

Tags: java, solr

I'm having two fields "name" and "price".I want to get its value.Consider, **name:Baseball** and **price:100**.

*Baseball* is of type *string* and **100** is *int*. I'm using the following code to get the value:

```
Field inputfield =docu.getField("name");

inputfield.stringValue();  //Output:Baseball (working)
```

Similarly, to get integer value (i.e 100) what i've to do?

Thanks,
Marshal

Answer (score 0):

All fields in Lucene are String values, you will have to do a Integer.parseInt() or equal for number fields.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getFieldValue` and casting:

```
Integer val = (Integer)docu.getFieldValue("myvar");
```